# Incorrect datetime value: ''2012-07-14 23:00:00''

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I'm having some trouble with the datetime format with Python/MySQL.

I calculate the datetime using the following script (fed by a Python dictionary):

```
tempDate  = str(eachday.get("date").get("year")).zfill(4) + "-" + 
str(eachday.get("date").get("month")).zfill(2) + "-" + 
str(eachday.get("date").get("day")).zfill(2)   + " " + 
str(eachday.get("date").get("hour")).zfill(2)  + ":" + 
str(eachday.get("date").get("min")).zfill(2)   + ":" + 
str(eachday.get("date").get("sec")).zfill(2)
```

Which yields a value that looks like `2012-04-02 04:04:23`.

I can insert into MySQL without any problems.

```
sql.execute("""INSERT INTO `db`.`table`(`id`, `fk_id`, `time`, `field1`, `field2`) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s);""", (fk_value, tempDate, value1, value2)) 
DB_CONN.commit()
```

But when I try to delete anything with that datetime,

```
sql.execute("""DELETE FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `time` = "%s";""", (tempDate))
DB_CONN.commit()
```

it returns a warning about an incorrect datetime value:

```
Warning: Incorrect datetime value: ''2012-07-17 23:00:00'' for column 'time' at row 1
```

How can I delete by datetime in Python? This is especially confusing since inserting the same variable (nothing changed) works perfectly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why so much work to build a string when you could just use datetime.strftime?

Comment: This is my first time programming Python. I've since switched it to the datetime as shown below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't include the quotes in `"%s"` in the query string; the mysqldb module adds them for you (same as it does in your `INSERT` where you don't try to put quotes around the values...)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Silly mistakes, helps to have another set of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily make use of the `datetime` module, which is a lot more controlled for building date strings:

```
from datetime import datetime

eachday = {
    'date': {
        'day': 2, 
        'hour': 4, 
        'min': 4, 
        'month': 4, 
        'sec': 23, 
        'year': 2012
    }
}
keys = ('year','month','day','hour','min','sec')
dt = datetime(*(eachday['date'][k] for k in keys))
print dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# '2012-04-02 04:04:23'
```

The benefit of sticking with a datetime, is that its the native format you will be getting from MySQLdb anyways. And you can pass it as a value with NO conversions. So really, formatting the date string isn't even needed.

```
sql.execute("DELETE FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `time`=%s", (dt,))
```

It is best to keep the datetime value as a datetime object as long as possible instead of carrying around int components.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched out my code and this looks much cleaner!