# MySQL OperationalError Incorrect datetime value

Tags: python, mysql, linux, mysql-python

While inserting time value from a given XML file it's throwing the below error

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '1509106091' for column 'last_update' at row 1")
```

And this is the sample XML file which my Python code reads the **endtime** value and dump into the MySQL database

```
<host starttime="1509105431" endtime="1509106091"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="245"/>
    <address addr="172.30.22.4" addrtype="ipv4"/>
    <hostnames>
```

And this is my Python MySQL query which insert the statement

```
t = (timestamp)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nmap.hosts VALUES (%s)",t)
```

And then I try to change to this both resulted in the same MySQL error

```
t = str((timestamp))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nmap.hosts VALUES (%s)",t)
```

The table NMAP last_update datatype is **TIMESTAMP**

```
 last_update TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Does anything on here help?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387510/incorrect-datetime-value-2012-07-14-230000

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with PHP?